# Trying to create a schedule for a GYM web

Tags: php, html

I finished my studies but now I need to develop a project and I thought about creating a web app for a gym, but I'm stuck on the schedule module. I need it to get the info from a database like this:

```
+--------+------------+--------+----------+------+-----------+------------+
| ID_Act | HoraInicio | Dia    | Duracion | Sala | DNI_Prof  | Dificultad |
+--------+------------+--------+----------+------+-----------+------------+
|      1 | 09:00:00   | LUNES  | 45       | 1    | 12345678A | 2          |
|      1 | 09:00:00   | MARTES | 45       | 1    | 12345678A | 3          |
|      1 | 10:30:00   | LUNES  | 45       | 1    | 12345678A | 1          |
+--------+------------+--------+----------+------+-----------+------------+
```

ID_Act: Activity ID

HoraInicio: Start time

Dia: Day

Duración: Duration

Sala: Room

DNI_Prof: Teacher ID

Dificultad: Level

I've been trying to create the whole schedule using a for loop so I don't have to copy&paste 50 rows. I can create the whole schedule with the loop but I can not print the values that I need to have in the proper cell.

This is the code of what I've been trying:

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <?php

    include("connbd.php");

    $consulta="SELECT actividades.nombre AS Actividad, ID_Act, HoraInicio, Dia, Duracion, Sala, Dificultad FROM horarios
             JOIN actividades WHERE actividades.id LIKE ID_Act;";

    $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);

    $hora = array("09:00","09:15","09:30","09:45","10:00","10:15","10:30","10:45","11:00","11:15","11:30",
      "11:45","12:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","13:15","13:30","13:45","14:00","14:15","14:30","14:45",
      "15:00","15:15","15:30","15:45","16:00","16:15","16:30","16:45","17:00","17:15","17:30","17:45","18:00",
      "18:15","18:30","18:45","19:00","19:15","19:30","19:45","20:00","20:15","20:30","20:45","21:00");

    ?>

    <div id=contenidoHorarios class="contenidoHorarios">
    <div id=contenidoHorariosTabla class="contenidoHorariosTabla">
    <div id=contenidoHorariosTablaHoras class="contenidoHorariosTablaHoras">

    <table border="1px" id="contenidoHorariosTablaTabla" class="contenidoHorariosTablaTabla">

                  <tr>
                    <th width="5%"></th>
                    <th width="13.57%">Lunes</th>
                    <th width="13.57%">Martes</th>
                    <th width="13.57%">Miércoles</th>
                    <th width="13.57%">Jueves</th>
                    <th width="13.57%">Viernes</th>
                    <th width="13.57%">Sábado</th>
                    <th width="13.57%">Domingo</th>
                  </tr>

    <?php
      foreach ($hora as $horatupla) {
     ?>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo $horatupla; ?></th>
      <td id="<?php
        while ($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc())
        {
          $id = $row['ID_Act'];
          $horainicio = substr($row['HoraInicio'],0,-3);
          $dia = $row['Dia'];
          $duracion = $row['Duracion'];
          $sala = $row['Sala'];
          $dificultad = $row['Dificultad'];
          $actividad = $row['Actividad'];


            if($dia=='LUNES'){echo $dia . $horatupla;} ?>" rowspan="<?php if($duracion=='15' || $duracion==''){echo '1';} if($duracion=='30'){echo '2';} if($duracion=='45'){echo '3';} ?>"

        <?php
            if ($horatupla==$horainicio)
              {
                echo $actividad;
              }
        }
        ?>>
      </td>
    </tr>

  <?php } ?>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I hope you understand what I'm saying, but to help you, I give you a example of what I do want to do (no spam).

http://www.go-fit.es/Horarios/Index

Comment: Please, add your code as text avoiding images.

Comment: @gp_sflover done, sorry, first time using stackoverflow to redact a question ^^'

Comment: You are welcome! You can read [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your future questions and get more attention = help :-)

Comment: No one knows? :(